# Fundamental form of explicit surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

I'm trying to derive the formulae for the fundamental forms of an  explicitly given surface $f(x,y)=z$ however I don't see how to set up my initial parametrisation. My intuition is that perhaps $\sigma (u,v)= (u,v, f(u,v))$ could be a natural starting point but I'm unsure if this is a correct assertion and whether this will induce the fundamental forms in terms of $f$ and it's derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick's answer is great, but in case you aren't comfortable with pull-backs and tensor products, you can use that the first fundamental form is expressed in coordinates by $${\rm d}s^2 = E\,{\rm d}u^2 + 2F\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v + G\,{\rm d}v^2,$$where $E = \langle \sigma_u,\sigma_u\rangle$, $F=\langle \sigma_u,\sigma_v\rangle$ and $G = \langle \sigma_v,\sigma_v\rangle$. You can readily compute $E = 1+f_u^2$, $F = f_uf_v$ and $G = 1 + f_v^2$, so:

$${\rm d}s^2 = (1+f_u^2)\,{\rm d}u^2 + 2f_uf_v\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v + (1+f_v^2)\,{\rm d}v^2.$$

Comment: Is this such that if $\gamma (t) = \sigma(u(t),v(t))$, then $ds=||\dot \gamma (t)||$? Just for the sake of argument/further understanding

Comment: The notation means $ds^2(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)) = \langle \gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)\rangle $. In coordinates this equals $$E(u(t),v(t)) u'(t)^2 + 2F(u(t),v(t)) u'(t)v'(t) + G(u(t),v(t)) v'(t)^2.$$

Comment: As an addendum, in the resources that I am using, the angle between any curves $\alpha, \beta$ is defined by $cos \theta = \frac{\dot \alpha \cdot \dot \beta}{||\dot \alpha||||\dot \beta||}$ and says that it is expressed in terms of the first fundamental form but this doesn't seem explicitly clear nor how the dot product is determined by the first fundamental form

Comment: Well, the first fundamental form is just the scalar product of the ambient $\Bbb R^3$ restricted to tangent vectors. All the vectors involved in the expression on the right side are tangent.

Comment: So the first fundamental form endows the dot product of any tangent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: And I presume that for any iso-parametric curves, the right hand side reduces readily into the form $\frac{F}{\sqrt{EG}}$ for an explicit verification?

Comment: I don't recall the term "iso-parametric", but in the general case the expression is ugly. The catch is that it only depends on $E, F, G$ and of the coordinates of the vectors in the basis $\{\sigma_u,\sigma_v\}$.

Comment: By iso-parametric, I mean that the curves in question for the parametrisation $\sigma (t) = (u(t),v(t))$, for two curves $u=u_0$ and $v=v_0$, would it be correct to assert that the angle, $\theta$, between the two curves is defined by $cos \theta = \frac{F}{\sqrt{EG}}$?

Comment: Or am I perhaps missing something here? Perhaps that the cosine of any such angle can be expressed as a scalar multiple of $\frac{F}{\sqrt{EG}}$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the correct way to go. If the surface is the graph of a smooth function $z = f(x,y)$, then putting graph coordinates on it (as you suggest), via $\sigma(x,y) = (x,y,f(x,y))$ will give the formulas you want. The "First Fundamental Form" is just the Riemannian metric. You can get it, in coordinates, by "pulling back" the standard Euclidean metric of $\Bbb{R}^3$ by $\sigma$. If $g = dx \otimes dx + dy \otimes dy + dz \otimes dz$ is the standard Euclidean metric (standard dot product), then the metric (1st fund. form) $\tilde{g}$ on your surface is the pull back of $g$ by the embedding:

$$
\tilde{g} = \sigma^* g 
$$

To compute this, note that $\sigma^* dx = dx$, $\sigma^*dy = dy$, and $\sigma^*dz = df = f_x dx + f_y dy$, and substitute:
$$
\begin {eqnarray}
\tilde{g} &=& dx \otimes dx + dy \otimes dy + df \otimes df \\
&=& (1 + f_x^2) \, dx \otimes dx + (1+f_y^2) \, dy \otimes dy + f_x f_y \left( dx \otimes dy + dy \otimes dx \right)
\end{eqnarray} $$

The Gram matrix for $\tilde{g}$ in these coordinates is 
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1+f_x^2 & f_x f_y \\ f_x f_y & 1+f_y^2
\end {array} \right)
$$